# Run script when someone telnet my server

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

> I Have:

1) Droplets on DigitalOcean ubuntu/debian/fedora

2) Simple script that echoes something  "script.sh"

> I want:

When someone telnets my Server from terminal: `telnet MY_DROPLET_IP` make my script.sh execute in his terminal and exit after that.

To sum up, I need something like this(check this out): `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installation:

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

/etc/xinetd.d/telnet file content:

```
service login
{
    port            = 23 
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/bin/script.sh       
    server_args     = test
}
```

/etc/xinetd.conf content:

```
{
# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info
instances = 60
log_type = SYSLOG authpriv
log_on_success = HOST PID
log_on_failure = HOST
cps = 25 30
}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

/etc/inetd.conf content:

```
telnet      stream  tcp nowait telnetd  /usr/bin/script.sh
```

Restart xinetd:

```
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

EDIT:
Don't forget

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

As telnet does not require a handshake, you could [set up xinetd to run the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519933/executing-script-on-receiving-incoming-connection-with-xinetd) on connections to port 23.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. I've solved issue and explained in my answer.